# Prevent Action button UIActivityViewController changing status bar text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, uiactivityviewcontroller, uistatusbar

I've implemented an Action (Share) button in a toolbar of my application. Upon tapping it, the action sheet - UIActivityViewController - pops up as expected, but it changes my previously black status bar text to white automatically. How do I prevent that so that it remains black? Thanks!

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.pasteboardField.text] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want to keep it black isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this line into your info.plist file:

> View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

[image]

Comment: Excellent. I'll need to remember I set that. :) Thanks!